# Can certain compile errors be suppressed in the Error List Dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When compiling a solution with many projects, if I make a compile time error in a project that many other projects use I'll get a flood of errors in the `Error List` window of visual studio:

```
Error   80  Metadata file
'C:\trunk\Projects\Libraries\K2DataBaseClient\bin\x64\Debug\CEPCortex.dll'
could not be found  C:\trunk\Projects\TradeAiTeacher\CSC
```

These errors indicate that a project couldn't be built due to another project not being built.  These types of errors cascade and don't really tell me anything useful as I know that its all due to a core project failing to build.

These errors often make it harder to find the actual error in the window.

Is there a way to tell visual studio to suppress this type of output and just show me the compile errors in cases like this to make it easy to find what actual code is broken?

Ideally it once the compile error has been fixed we can toggle this hiding off so I see all errors.

I had originally left this version agnostic but visual-studio 2013 is the version I am most concerned with.

Comment: Which version? There are extensions that allow stopping compilation of all projects after the very first error occurs, seems sort of what you are after

Comment: @stijn I've updated the question, I'm using visual-studio-2013

Comment: could try this extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/91aaa139-5d3c-43a7-b39f-369196a84fa5?SRC=VSIDE or build one yourself http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/29/visual-studio-plugin-stop-build-at-first-error/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the best way to work with existing the visual studio behavior is to use the advice in [this link:](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/08/29/visual-studio-plugin-stop-build-at-first-error/) and make the compiler stop after the first compile error.

This seems to get as close to solving my problem as you currently can.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The C# compiler categorically refuses to consider one error more "important" than another one.  It cannot know how important an error can be, it doesn't know enough about the *reason* it had to produce the error.  A missing reference assembly can produce a *lot* of errors because type definitions are missing.  Of course the compiler cannot know the difference between them being undefined because of the missing assembly reference (ignore) or you mistyping a name (don't ignore).

Interpreting the Error List requires a massively parallel computing machine that's capable of high-speed correlation inference and pattern matching.  With practical quantum computing still a distant future, you need to use the one that's readily available to any programmer, the one you have between your ears.  Start at the top of the list.  And work your way down, feeling less inclined to fix them as you progress down the list.

Never hesitate to rebuild before getting to the end of the list when you fixed a gross error.  Like a missing assembly reference.